# Inserting elements of one list into another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `J1` and `Leftover`. I want to insert elements of `Leftover` into `J1` at locations of `0` elements of `J1` and ensure that new `J1` has all non-zero elements in ascending order. I want the length of old and new `J1[0]` to be the same. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np
J1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Leftover=[1,4]

for i in range(0,len(Leftover)): 
    J1.insert(Leftover[i],i) 
print("J1 =",J1)
```

The current output is

```
J1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0], 0, 1]
```

The expected output is

```
J1 = [[1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
```

Comment: J1 is a list and only item/first element of J1 is also a list. you want all elements of J1 in ascending order. But your expected output is not in ascending order. What you want is not clear.

Comment: In your own words: 1) Where the code says `import numpy as np`, **why**? What relevance do you expect this to have, to the rest of the code that is shown? 2) Where the code says `J1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]`, *exactly what do you think this means*? In particular, what do  you think is the effect of using *two* brackets on each side? Do you see how this relates to the `.insert` logic? 3) Where the code says `J1.insert(Leftover[i],i) `, *how do you intend for this to work*? Each time this line of code runs, what do you think will be the value of `i`, and of `Leftover[i]`? What should happen?

Comment: Please try to work through the logic of the code carefully first, and [check what actually happens](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), step by step, as the code runs. If a *specific thing* happens at a *specific point* that confuses you, then you can ask a *specific question* about that unexpected result. Otherwise, the problem is in the logic of your approach to the task, and solving the problem is a matter of thinking more clearly, not about learning something new about Python or about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sorts even elements that are `0`.

```
J1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Leftover=[1,4]
J1[0].extend(Leftover)
J1[0].sort()
# J1:
# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 9]]
```

Since `J1` is a list with a single list inside, you need to add new elements to `J1[0]` instead of `J1`.

Note that the solution doesn't require `numpy`.

---

To *replace* elements that are `0` (instead of lengthening the list), do this:

```
J1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Leftover=[1,4]

for lftovr in Leftover:
    for i in range(len(J1[0])):
        if J1[0][i] == 0:
            J1[0][i] = lftovr
            break
# J1:
# [[1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 9, 0]]

J1[0].sort()
# J1:
# [[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 9]]
```

Note that sorting elements without rearranging the `0`s is an underspecified task from your post's description: What if the original list is something like `[3, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 9]` and you would like to insert `2` and `5`? To get something like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 9]`, we would need to rearrange the original order of the items; pure replacement of `0`s can't do the job. But if we sort, we might as well sort the whole list (including the `0`s).

---

Some assumptions you might be making that would make the problem better-defined:

- the original list's non-`0` elements are already in sorted order
- the required insertions can be done without rearranging any of the initial non-`0` elements
- there is enough space in the list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert Leftover in first element of J1 and sort first element of J1 in ascending order. Then the code will be:

```
J1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Leftover=[1,4]
J1[0].extend(Leftover)
J1[0].sort()
print("J1 =", J1)
```

> Output will be: J1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 9]]

Comment: I edited my post. Please have a look.